# Making my color set to a variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to set my color in a span style to a variable...anyone know why this is wrong?

```
<span style="font-weight:bold; color:"<%= AccountWarningStyle %>"; font-size:14px;"></span>
```

AccountWarningStyle is my c# variable

Comment: What is happening that tells you that this is wrong?  Please post any errors you receive, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens that you consider to be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the extra quote marks from around the `<%= AccountWarningStyle%>".  This will render as:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold; color:"red"; font-size:14px;">
```

Where it should be:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:14px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have quotation marks around your C# code: "<% ... %>".
The first quote makes your browser think your style attribute is finished immediately after "color:"

Answer (score 0):

try declaring span

```
<span id="MySpan" runat="server" />
```

and then assign color in code behind

do check [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(VS.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28VS.71%29.aspx)